# sharepoint 2010 - jquery code to get attachment name

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

In a sharepoint 2010 new form for a links list, I created a content editor webpart and put this jquery code in to get the filename for the attachment document (if user attached one).

Essentially I am trying to turn a links list into a document library in order to utilize its item ordering feature.

This is the code I am using in the new form.aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.ms-ButtonHeightWidth').eq(2).mousedown( function ( event ) {
        var my_array = $(".ms-vb");
        for (var i=0; i<my_array.length; i++) {
            text = $(my_array[i]).html();
            text = text.substring(1, text.length);
            text = text.substring(text.indexOf(">")+1, text.indexOf("<"));
            filename = text.substr(text.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);
            document.getElementById('ctl00_m_g_0440ff9f_32fb_44b5_8b6d_a9055bcb9806_ctl00_ctl05_ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte').innerHTML = filename;
        }
    });
</script>
```

it basically puts a mouse down event on the save button, that changes a column field value to the attachment filename. its mouse down because it needs to happen before the save function occurs.
After this a workflow occurs and changes this column field value into a hyperlink to the document.

I want to know if the above code has no flaws. I mean like is it safe to use and won't break ever? Currently it works for me.

EDIT: (this is the code for the save button in the new form)

```
<input name="ctl00$m$g_0440ff9f_32fb_44b5_8b6d_a9055bcb9806$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" id="ctl00_m_g_0440ff9f_32fb_44b5_8b6d_a9055bcb9806_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl00_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem" accessKey="O" onclick="if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$m$g_0440ff9f_32fb_44b5_8b6d_a9055bcb9806$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem", "", true, "", "", false, true))" type="button" target="_self" jQuery17203303955991604388="1" value="Save"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could see it possibly having a problem by not finishing before the save function occurs. If possible, try to override the button's default submit handler with an `event.preventDefault();` and then calling the default submit function after your code is completed.

Edit:
Code that might work:

```
$('.ms-ButtonHeightWidth').eq(2).click( function ( event ) {
    // Stop default save function
    event.preventDefault();

    // Add in filename of attachment
    var my_array = $(".ms-vb");
    for (var i=0; i<my_array.length; i++) {
        text = $(my_array[i]).html();
        text = text.substring(1, text.length);
        text = text.substring(text.indexOf(">")+1, text.indexOf("<"));
        filename = text.substr(text.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);
        document.getElementById('ctl00_m_g_0440ff9f_32fb_44b5_8b6d_a9055bcb9806_ctl00_ctl05_ctl03_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte').innerHTML = filename;
    }

    // Run default save function
    if (PreSaveItem()) {
        WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$m$g_0440ff9f_32fb_44b5_8b6d_a9055bcb9806$ctl00$toolBarTbl$RightRptControls$ctl00$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem", "", true, "", "", false, true));
    }
});
```

Comment: I put the code of the save button above, can you show me how to do this?

Comment: Try using the code in my edit above. I changed the event to a click and then stopped the default click event and then ran your code. I then put the code from the button's onclick attribute after your's so it would run. I'm hoping that the ids used by the button aren't really dynamic.